# Where to find via() method and Notifiable model in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel-5, push-notification, laravel-notification

I want to use [laravel-notification-channels/ionic-push-notifications](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/ionic-push-notifications) package in Laravel 5.3 app. but I can't find via() method and Notifiable model that are mentioned in the [package documentation](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/ionic-push-notifications). where can I find them ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that I should use `make:notification` artisan command first to create a notification class in app/Notifications directory. Then, I'll find via() method inside this class.

The Notifiable model isn't a model whose name is "Notifiable", but any model can be Notifiable model (the model that I want to send a notification to an instance of it ) by making it use the Notifiable trait :

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use App\Notifications\MyNotificationClass;

class MyModel extends Model
{

    use Notifiable;

    ....

}
```